# innerJoin query show error

Tags: php, inner-join

just i print the two table data so i am using inner join

```
SELECT  sd.GameName 
FROM LottoryTickets AS sd
    JOIN group AS p 
    ON sd.Group = p.groupname 
WHERE p.groupname = 11
```

now i get #106`4 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group AS p ON sd.Group = p.groupname WHERE p.groupname = 11 LIMIT 0, 30' at line 3`

this response please guide me

thanks for advance.

Comment: group is a key word, so you can't use it as a table name or field name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`group` is a keyword in MySQL, if you want to call a table by that name, you have to surround the name with backticks;

```
SELECT  sd.GameName 
FROM LottoryTickets AS sd
    JOIN `group` AS p 
    ON sd.Group = p.groupname 
WHERE p.groupname = 11
```

Answer (score 6):

use:

```
`group` //as group is a predefined keyword
```

Answer (score 0):

GROUP is ansi sql reserved word. eaven submitted code that is evident (group is colored in blue).

TRY

```
SELECT  sd.GameName 
FROM LottoryTickets AS sd
    JOIN `group` AS p 
    ON sd.Group = p.groupname 
WHERE p.groupname = 11
```